# Will an If statement stop checking if the first OR condition is met?

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog

Does SystemVerilog evaluate the whole `if` statement or the minimum to get the result?

For example:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) begin
  ...
end

if (condition1 || condition2) begin
  ...
end
```

In the first case, will `condition2` be evaluated if `condition1` is False?
In the second case, will `condition2` be evaluated if `condition1` is True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is also known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Refer to IEEE 1800-2017, section 11.4.7 *Logical operators*.

```
The && and || operators shall use short circuit evaluation as follows:
    — The first operand expression shall always be evaluated.
    — For &&, if the first operand value is logically false then the second 
      operand shall not be evaluated.
    — For ||, if the first operand value is logically true then the second 
      operand shall not be evaluated.
```

Therefore, for the operators in your `if` statements, all the expressions may not be evaluated.

To see which operators have similar behavior, and which do not, refer to section 11.3.5 *Operator expression short circuiting*.